# how do I convert a binary file to ascii for source control?

Tags: version-control, file-conversion

I'm all too well aware that the answer here, in the general case, is "you don't." The reason I'm asking is that a PM at SAP is asking me why a TXT output of a Crystal Report doesn't meet my needs. In the past, I've seen converters for binary files (.doc in particular, iirc) that worked smoothly with Subversion (or maybe TortoiseSVN) to convert the files to ASCII and back so that merging/branching/reconciling actually worked. I'd like to be able to point at them and say "This is what I need", but I'm darned if I can remember the Google search that pulled them up last time. Can anyone save me a little pain and point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using SVN you could use properties to tell him that it is binary. In case you really want, the first solution that came to my mind (but not a very efficient) is to use uuencode / uudecode.

Comment: I know, but once I tell SVN it's binary, I'm no longer able to reconcile conflicts -- it's all or nothing. uuencode has much the same problem-- if I try to merge changes, I'm likely to wind up with something completely unusable.

Comment: then you need a specific converter for your specific binary type, like pdf2text (where many formating get lost). But as binary can be anything (imagine executables) there is no general routine, that has the converting knowledge except such stuff as uuencode, or hexdump/od.

Comment: /specific converter/ Yes, that's essentially what I asked for above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not so much the difference between binary or ASCII, but rather if a line-oriented diff/conflict resolution is what you need. Even a non-ASCII solution like UTF-8 XML could help (and brings "interesting" problems with regard to ordering of elements on the same level).

The most standard way of encoding binaries is probably [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. Implementations are readily available in all shapes and flavours. Of course it'll increase the size of the file, and I'd bet that SVN can only ever preserve the prefix of the file if there's a change, as the subsequent encoded data after the point of change will be completely different.